# Input cell address, get table name

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for some excel VBA code that when I input a cell address it'll give me the name of the table that that cell is apart of of and store the name of the table in a variable. I would also like to store the cell address in a variable called "GetCellsTable".

Is there anyway I can go about doing this?

Example:

```
Dim StoreTableName as String?
Dim GetCellsTable as ?
StoreTableName = Range(GetCellsTable).ListObject.Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyVariable = SomeCell.ListObject.Name
```

Edit:

If you want to store the cell address (say cell "A3") in a variable and then use it to get the table name:

```
Dim GetCellsTable As String
GetCellsTable = "A3"
MyTableName = Range(GetCellsTable).ListObject.Name
```

Or, if you want to store the cell itself as a range object in a variable:

```
Dim GetCellsTable as Range
Set GetCellsTable = Range("A3")
MyTableName = GetCellsTable.ListObject.Name
```

Comment: So would I use it like this?:
StoreTableName = A3.ListObject.Name

Comment: StoreTableName = Range("A3").ListObject.Name

Comment: And how about if I'd like to have that range stored in a variable called "GetCellsTable"? I am getting close to what I need as I tinker.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean you want to create a function called GetCellsTable?

Comment: I was thinking something like this:
Dim GetCellsTable as ?
StoreTableName = Range(GetCellsTable).ListObject.Name
I am just not sure if that is the correct way to state this.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are after. Perhaps you can provide some context? See my edit above which is maybe what you are after.

Comment: Actually I believe what you stated in your first code snippet was what I was looking for. Thank you!